# Storing and showing html contents in mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am doing email fetch and storing html email body in mysql db,
When i pull that data in html view with controller, my html page gets link type underlines on all words on pages,

Below contents are stored in mysql db,

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
<meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 14 (filtered medium)">
<!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);} o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);} w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);} .shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);} </style><![endif]-->
<style>
<!-- /* Font Definitions */ @font-face {font-family:Calibri; panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;} @font-face {font-family:Tahoma; panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;} /* Style Definitions */ p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal {margin:0in; margin-bottom:.0001pt; font-size:11.0pt; font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";} a:link, span.MsoHyperlink {mso-style-priority:99; color:blue; text-decoration:underline;} a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed {mso-style-priority:99; color:purple; text-decoration:underline;} p.MsoAcetate, li.MsoAcetate, div.MsoAcetate {mso-style-priority:99; mso-style-link:"Balloon Text Char"; margin:0in; margin-bottom:.0001pt; font-size:8.0pt; font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";} span.EmailStyle17 {mso-style-type:personal-compose; font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif"; color:windowtext;} span.BalloonTextChar {mso-style-name:"Balloon Text Char"; mso-style-priority:99; mso-style-link:"Balloon Text"; font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";} .MsoChpDefault {mso-style-type:export-only; font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";} @page WordSection1 {size:8.5in 11.0in; margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;} div.WordSection1 {page:WordSection1;} -->
</style>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> <o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" /> </xml><![endif]-->
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> <o:shapelayout v:ext="edit"> <o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" /> </o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body lang="EN-US" link="blue" vlink="purple">
<div class="WordSection1">
    <p class="MsoNormal">Hello,
        <o:p></o:p>
    </p>
    <p class="MsoNormal">
        <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
    </p>
    <p class="MsoNormal">See below image
        <o:p></o:p>
    </p>
    <p class="MsoNormal">
        <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
    </p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><img width="574" height="503" id="Picture_x0020_1" src="cid:image001.png@01D07787.D6E979E0">
        <o:p></o:p>
    </p>
    <p class="MsoNormal">
        <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
    </p>
    <p class="MsoNormal">Regards,
        <o:p></o:p>
    </p>
    <p class="MsoNormal">Njoy.
        <o:p></o:p>
    </p>
    <p class="MsoNormal">
        <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
    </p>
</div>
</body></html>
```

First i printed with below simple echo,

```
<?php echo $html_data['htmlbody'];?>
```

With above echo, my html page got link type underlines for all words in page, means something crossing in html pages,

Then i tried to applied below command,
But with this, i just got output as shown in above html code,
No real message, but with this time my html page stays good, no issue with formatting.

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($html_data['htmlbody']);?>
```

In short,
How to show html formatted data which is stored in mysql db in HTML view page?

See below img.

[image: Here is image]

Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean you want to show the HTML in the browser, not just when viewing the source?

Comment: Want to show in browser

Comment: I just tested this in phpFiddle and it behaves as expected. no underlines and html renders correctly.

Comment: can you screenshot what it renders please.

Comment: @StuartWickenden, This html renders correctly in display div, but other contents of my html page lost its formatting, means shows underlines with links.

Comment: Ok, but you are rendering the HTML from the database with html head and body tags. If you are doing that into a page your source will likely clash. you cannot have multple html/head/body tags. I guess the issue is clashing of tags on some level. Impossible to tell without seeing in full what you are working with.

Comment: You can do a workaround for it... Display all the data from database in separate file say data_fromDB.php and use farmeset to display data_formDB.php this solves your problem

Comment: @StuartWickenden, you are correct, but how can i show that so that it will not clash, or how do i pass my data to mysql by removing html tags, attached image in main post

Comment: @RahulMishra, frameset tag not supported in HTML 5

Comment: Either use IFrame or do not render html from the database and instead render the content without the tags.

Comment: @StuartWickenden, OK will try that, next test i did ,is passed RichText email content and it works perfectly even though it have html and body tags, strange!

Comment: Although that may work it would unlikely be a valid document. If validity is no issue to you then solution found i guess?

Comment: @StuartWickenden, i assume now i have final solution found, i digging in HTML code and found that by removing <style></style> tags and contents inside this tag, reserves my HTML page perfectly and shows my html with good rendering. Now i need to write code for removing this tags and contents between this two tags before entering in mysql db,

Comment: yes. The clash would be directly because of the style tags. Iframe renders without issue as style is kept within its Iframe and does not affect the parent document. I would still suggest the best method for what you are trying to achieve is to store your html wrapper separately for sending emails, and store the content separate so you can see it without having to be tedious with the style tags.  This is how i manage my content between site and emails.